# Is バッチリ a generally accepted term?

Tags: words

Is バッチリ a generally used, non-slangy, and well recognised word?

I couldn't find the word in jisho.org or the Japanese edition of Wiktionary. I could find it in [weblio](http://ejje.weblio.jp/content/%E3%83%90%E3%83%83%E3%83%81%E3%83%AA), and apparently it means "excellent", but when it was listing examples, two of the three examples seemed unrelated ("除去可能なサセプタを伴う熱バッチリアクタ" and "バッチリアクター内でのＴｉＮ膜の堆積", which were examples involving the katakana word for "batch" instead).

Comment: http://jisho.org/words?jap=%E3%81%B0%E3%81%A3%E3%81%A1%E3%82%8A&eng=&dict=edict

Comment: http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/leaf/jn2/177688/m0u/%E3%81%B0%E3%81%A3%E3%81%A1%E3%82%8A/

Comment: I'd recommend using the beta.jisho.org site instead of the regular jisho.org.  It is able to find entries in both syllabaries, which the old site can't: http://beta.jisho.org/search/%E3%83%90%E3%83%83%E3%83%81%E3%83%AA

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is more than just a common word; It is used everywhere except for in formal, technical, business or academic **writing** as the word has a light and somewhat onomatopoeic quality to it.  It is not really slangy although it is informal.

It is the kind of word that makes a conversation sound alive as it gives a certain rhythm that just sounds good to native speakers.

There are ***so many*** words consisting of four kana with a small 「っ/ッ」in the second and a 「り/リ」 in the final spots.  Most of these words (mostly adverbs) share the onomatopoeic quality that I mentioned above.  None of them are formal words, either.　All are completely originally Japanese with no Sino or other influence.

Examples: ぴったり、しっとり、もっちり、べったり、がっかり、しっかり、ばったり、どっきり、etc.  The list would be near-endless, trust me.  (And these happen to be the sore spot for many Japanese learners as well because it is difficult to translate them.  At least, the translations will not be just 4-letter long.)

Finally, I personally assure you that the word has nothing to do with "**batch reactor**" = 「**バッチリ**アクター」.

Comment: So that explains why there isn't a kanji form for the word!

Comment: "The list would be near-endless, trust me." I started compiling such a list some time ago, precisely because it is a sore spot for myself, as it must be for all Japanese learners. My list isn't endless, yet (it has, by chance, exactly 100 entries), but looking at this list from time to time is always a good occasion for humility by serving as a reminder that Japanese is still a long way away.

Comment: @Earthliŋ For the curious, have you made this compiled list publicly accessible?